# Docusign embedded signing with more than 1 signer

Tags: docusignapi

I have created an iFrame in my application to display Docusign embedded signing for single recipient by generating embedded Url using [these](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/embedding) steps.

But I have 3 recipients with different signing order.  How to generate separate Urls for same envelope to display on 3 different pages of my website?

Comment: It's ill-advised to put DocuSign in an iFrame for UX reasons, especially for users on a mobile browser.

Comment: There should be a `RecipientViewRequest` object that you can make, giving it the recipients info & returnUrl. Then call `createRecipientView`.

Answer (score 0):

there's a recipientId that's unique for each recipient.
Since you're embedding the signatures, there's also a clientUserId that is required and should be different for each recipient you are embedding.